# Infinite limit of trigonometric function

Tags: calculus, infinity

I'm trying to find the limit of a trigonometric function as x approaches $\infty$ so I can't use the fact that : $$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{1}{x} = 0$$

For example this limit : 
$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{\cos(x) - 1}{x}$$

Or

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{\sin(x)}{\lfloor x \rfloor}$$

Questions are from Thomas Calculus

Comment: I'm unsure of what you're asking. Are you attempting to prove these facts?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prove that $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}x=1$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75130/how-to-prove-that-lim-limits-x-to0-frac-sin-xx-1) if you intended to have limit as $x\to 0$.

Comment: @JMoravitz The limit is $x\to \infty$, not $0$

Comment: In the case of $x\to\infty$ the numerator is bounded while the denominator is unbounded.

Comment: The =0 in the text was my bad I want to find these limits

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $$-1\leq \sin(x),\cos(x)\leq 1$$ so numerator is just a number oscillating from $-1$ to $1$.  Some number between $-1$ and $1$ divided by $\infty$ is $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Notice:

- $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\cos(x)-1}{x}$$

Since $\cos(x)-1$ is bounded and $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{x}=0$ this limit equals $0$.

- $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sin(x)}{\lfloor x\rfloor}$$

Since $\sin(x)$ is bounded and $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{\lfloor x\rfloor}=0$ this limit equals $0$.